# Get values within keys with item loader scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to extract some values from keys in the response page of a webpage. Unfortunately, when I do this it returns the keys only and I cannot seem to grab the values. Because each key is a long list and they're numbered I cannot seem to figoure out how to get the values for all of them.

For example, here's my working code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.item import Field
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst

class DepopItem(scrapy.Item):
    brands = Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())

class DepopSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'depop'
    allowed_domains = ["depop.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/filters/aggregates/?brands=1596&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance']

    
    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
    }
    
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url, 
                callback=self.parse,
             )

    def parse(self, response):
        resp= response.json()['brands']
        for item in resp:
            loader = ItemLoader(DepopItem(), selector=item)
            loader.add_value('brands', item)
 
            yield loader.load_item()
```

This returns a list of the keys:

```
{"brands": "1"}
{"brands": "2"}
{"brands": "3"}
{"brands": "4"}
{"brands": "5"}
{"brands": "7"}
{"brands": "9"}
```

Instead I want the values corresponding to these keys:

```
{"brands": 946}
{"brands": 2376}
{"brands": 1286}
{"brands": 2774}
{"brands": 489}
{"brands": 11572}
{"brands": 1212}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use `values()` or `resp[item]`.

Example:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.item import Field
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst


class DepopItem(scrapy.Item):
    brands = Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())


class DepopSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'depop'
    allowed_domains = ["depop.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/filters/aggregates/?brands=1596&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance']

    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        resp = response.json()['brands']
        for item in resp.values():
            loader = ItemLoader(DepopItem(), selector=item)
            loader.add_value('brands', item['count'])
            yield loader.load_item()
```

Output:

```py
{'brands': 888}
{'brands': 1}
{'brands': 52}
{'brands': 138}
{'brands': 148}
...
...
...
```

Comment: Ah so simple! I wouldn't have ever got it though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how about scrapy but you could simply do:

```
import requests
import json
from itertools import starmap
from requests.models import Response
from typing import Dict, List


url = "https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/filters/aggregates/?brands=1596&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance"
resp: Response = requests.get(url)
data: Dict = json.loads(resp.text).get("brands")
values: List[Dict] = list(starmap(lambda k,v: {"brands": v["count"]}, data.items()))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{'brands': 989},
 {'brands': 1838},
 {'brands': 2415},
 {'brands': 1344},
 ...]
```

Comment: I know this approach it's what I'm currently doing but I specifically want scrapy to improve my skills with it. Thanks for the attempt!